# install pdf-tools without sudo

Tags: pdf-tools, sudo

I have installed (a working version of (doom)) Emacs on a remote linux cluster (via conda) for which I do not have sudo access, my question is:

how can I install pdf-tools?

Thanks

Assume I can install the backend poppler (I think I can). Do I need to install other supporting programs as well?

Comment: Did you follow [these installation instructions](https://github.com/vedang/pdf-tools#installing-pdf-tools)?